# respond json object with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
var http = require('http')
  ,https = require('https')
  ,fs = require('fs'),json;

var GOOGLE_API_KEY = process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY;

var FUSION_TABLE_ID = "1epTUiUlv5NQK5x4sgdy1K47ACDTpHH60hbng1qw";

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
  port: 443,
  path: "/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20"+FUSION_TABLE_ID+"FROM%20&key="+GOOGLE_API_KEY,
  method: 'GET'
};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("chapters.json");
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      file.write(data);
    }).on('end', function() {
      file.end();
    });
  });
  req.end();
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
  console.log(req);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end('Hello JSON');

}).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 8337, null);
```

how do i return the json object rather then the 'Hello JSON'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store the received data in a file, put it in a local variable instead, and then send that variable in `res.end()`:

```
var clientRes = res;
var json = '';

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        json += data;
    }).on('end', function() {
        // send the JSON here
        clientRes.writeHead(...);
        clientRes.end(json);
    });
});
```

Note that you have two `res` variables - one for the response you're sending back to your own clients, and one which is the response you're receiving from Google.  I've called the former `clientRes`.

Alternatively, if you're just going to proxy the information unmodified, you can just put `clientRes.write(data, 'utf8')` inside the `res.on('data')` callback:

```
http.createServer(function (clientReq, clientRes) {

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            clientRes.write(data, 'utf8');
        }).on('end', function() {
            clientRes.end();
        });

    clientRes.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type: 'application/json'});
    clientReq.end().on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });

});
```

Comment: @khinester which did you use?

Comment: here is the code: https://github.com/TZM/Z-Tabzilla/commit/b8808b1330a2955a26c14811439667dfff66ace6#L4R18

Comment: @khinester right - you just copy straight from the server to the client.  I note you haven't added a `Content-Type` in your client output.  Also the `json` variable is unnecessary because you never store anything in it.  That's only used in my first answer to accumulate the content from the server.

Comment: yes the idea is to pull the data frol the FT and populate the javascript widget with the links, as i don't keep track of this list. i will add the Content-Type and remove the json var; thanks for pointing it out.